# Some problems with nlsLM... R

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

I’m using the package `minpack.lm` to represent a nonlinear equation in a dataset.  I thought I understood the script but I´m obtaining a very annoying error running the following script.

```
library(minpack.lm);
x<-c(0,2,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,18,20);x<-x/20;
y<-c(0,0.0014,0.41165,0.6258,0.357,0.46657,0.1803,0.05844,0.10185,0.0085,0.000933)
med<-cbind(x,y)
med=data.frame(med)
windows()
fm=function(x,beta1,beta2){(x^(beta1-1))*((1-x)^(beta2-1))}
plot(y~x,data=med)
m5=nlsLM(y~fm(x,beta1,beta2),data=med,start=list(beta1=0.1,beta2=1),trace=TRUE)
summary(m5)
b=coef(m5)
curve(fm(x,beta1=b["beta1"],beta2=b["beta2"]),add=TRUE)
```

The error is something like this:

> "Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) :    Missing
>   value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model"

I dont understand quite sure why this is happening... Can any of you help me?

I have an extra question... I need to introduce in the x axis specific words in specific x values, for example in x = 0.1 I need to introduce “phase 1” and in x = 0.2 "phase2" what is the best option to do this?

Comment: Try `fm(x, 0.1, 1)`. As some `x` are zero, when beta1 < 1 then  `x^(beta1-1)` will equal `Inf`. So get sensible starting values

Comment: Thanks for your help! but I´m still getting the same error

Comment: I didnt mean to remove the zeros, instead set the starting value for beta1 >= 1.(ie try beta1 = 1)

Comment: Ok! thanks man! as you said the problem is with the 0,0... If I remove it the error dissapear. However Im loosing this point.

Comment: The problem is not really with the zero but with the starting values. These values need to provide a reasonable starting point for the iterations (although the LM alg is quite forgiving to poor starting values). As some x values are zero, because you start beta1 at 0.1, then these x values evaluate at 0^(0.1-1) = 0^(-0.9) which equal to (1 / 0^0.9) = Inf. So obviously the algorithm cannot proceed from this value. So try setting beta1 >= 1 as a starting value (do not remove the zero x values)

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user20650, post as answer ...

Comment: @BenBolker; I am reluctant as I dont have the knowledge to propose a scheme for selecting the starting values, other than plug some in. (or something along these lines `coef(lm(log(y) ~ 0 + log(x) + log(1-x), data=med[-c(1, nrow(med)),]))`)